# How can I keep my cross-platform GUI application up to date?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, wxwidgets, upgrade

I'm writing a GUI application in C++ using [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets). As I develop this, I would like to roll out updates to my customers in a reasonably light-weight and customer-friendly way.

My first thoughts were the traditional: go check a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) for a version number and if it's different from the current one, tell the user there's a new version to download (maybe present them with a download link).

Is there a more intelligent/customer-friendly way to do this?

Comment: Hmm... I guess this is a partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711435/has-anybody-used-google-omaha-their-auto-update-engine-for-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://winsparkle.org/ (it's Windows-only but for Mac you have the original Sparkle and under Linux you usually rely on the packaging system for the updates instead of doing it yourself).

Comment: Would that mean I'd need to make separate packages for each flavour of linux (I've only ever developed on windows or embedded platforms)?

Comment: @JonCage AFAIK there are only 2 major package formats, RPM and .deb, which should be sufficient.

Comment: Sparkle looks far more polished than WebUdpdate - thanks; I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

I found a potential cross-platform solution:

> [WebUpdate](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/webupdate/) is a complete, open source, cross-platform update solution for any type of application. It provides an easily-integrable, small application which connects to a web server and shows the updated packages to the user (supports multiple packages) and let him download and install them.
>
> Reliable downloads are granted using [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) checksums. Local updates (for example, updates to be taken from a CD-ROM or any other device) are supported, too. The program is highly configurable using XML and XRC files. For a complete list of the features of WebUpdate, look at the [WebUpdate documentation](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/docs/webupdate/).